# How to join result from two tables with same field into one field Codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I use Codeigniter

My invalid SQL query:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT menu FROM sepetim WHERE SiparisId = S.Id) AS menum
FROM siparisler AS S
WHERE onay = 1 AND BayiId = '1'
ORDER BY Id desc
```

I have tables like this:

```
 Table1           Table2
   Id             Id | Text
    1             1    name1
    2             1    name2
                  2    name3
```

Current result:
[image]

Wanted result:
[image]

Can you help me? Thanx.

Comment: Your query has siparisler and sepetim, but then you say Table1 and Table2...

Comment: @jarlh That's just one example dude :)

Comment: That makes no sense at all. And your images include columns not specified. Redo! Simplify, skip images - add formatted text instead. Have consistent table and column names etc!

Comment: @jarlh Okay. http://i.hizliresim.com/5YNZdA.png Did it help ?